# How do I resolve "No such file or directory" with Python os.rename module

Tags: python, file, rename

Here is my code:

```
file_list = os.listdir("/home/vanessa/prank")   

    def rename_files():
        # current_dir = os.getcwd()

        for file_name in file_list:
            os.rename(file_name, file_name.translate(None, "0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9"))


rename_files()
```

When I run, i get

> ***os.rename(file_name, file_name.translate(None, "0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9"))
>   OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify the full path to your file, not just the relative path. You can do that by calling `os.getcwd` and joining the result to the tail with `os.path.join`.

```
def rename_files():
    root = "/home/vanessa/prank"

    for file_name in file_list:
        os.rename(os.path.join(root, file_name), 
                  os.path.join(root, file_name.translate(None,
                                                   "0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9")))
```

Answer (score 0):

os.listdir() returns just name of the files , not paths. add path to the files.

Comment: I don't get, how please @akp

Comment: same. says os.rename("/home/vanessa/prank" + str(file_name), file_name.translate(None, "0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9"))
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: @Vanessa There are 3 answers, of which only one has been upvoted. Why are you ignoring it?

Comment: @coldspeed, the program is supposed to rename files in the prank folder and strip of numbers. Actually, I'm a python newbie.

Comment: You're missing a path separator.

Comment: `"/home/vanessa/prank/"+str(file_name)`

Comment: os.rename("/home/vanessa/prank//"+str(file_name), "/home/vanessa/prank//"+file_name.translate(None, "0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9"))

Answer (score -2):

try absolute path instead of relative path

```
file_list = os.listdir("/home/vanessa/prank")
```

to

```
file_list = os.listdir("C:/home/vanessa/prank")
```

Comment: OP is obviously running on *Nix, this isn't going to do anything.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu linux, is "C" still applicable?

Comment: @Vanessa No, it most certainly won't.

Comment: thought so too @coldspeed